# Find which laptop component is slow

Tags: laptop, lenovo-laptop

I have a 3 years old Lenovo carbon x1 laptop with i5 and 8 gb ram, it has been serving me well, but for the last 6 months the computer is unbearably slow: it takes a lot of time for programs to load and the computer freezes often. I have already formatted the laptop and even fresh clean installs are slow. I have also updated windows and Lenovo firmware and BIOS.

How can I check what part of the laptop is causing the issue so I can replace it? Is there a way to test cpu/hd/ram speed to find the culprit?

Thanks!

Edit: other stuff that are maybe important to mentio, I have an SSD drive, don't notice too long boot time or high percentages of cpu or ram.

Answer (score 3):

CPU and memory extremely rarely fail.  When they do, the results are far more disastrous, as in the computer will not work at all, or it will crash constantly.  That doesnt sound like your issue.

Traditional hard disk drives are the most common parts to fail in a computer.  It is possible yours is failing.  Here is a [guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/134735/how-to-see-if-your-hard-drive-is-dying/) on how to check its [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) status.  SMART is a drive's diagnostic tool to monitor itself.  If you find it is failing, consider purchasing a SSD.  SSDs have no moving parts and are significantly faster than traditional HDDs.

Another possibility is overheating.  Laptops can suck in a lot of dust that gets stuck inside.  This prevents air from flowing and properly cooling the laptop.  Overheating laptops can display similar issues as yours.  Here is a [guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/194479/how-to-clean-the-dust-out-of-your-laptop/) on how to clean your laptop.

Comment: Thanks. I have a SSD drive so drive failure is unlikely, I'll check whether the laptop is overheating

Comment: @AlonMln don't count out the SSD. Test it. Cheap SSDs arebk own to fail.